# Trigger modal from dropdown menu click event antd

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

So i have a `<Modal/>` which is controlled by a state `Visible`, i want to be able to change the state of this modal from a dropdown menu inside a table row from Antd using `SetVisible` but i cannot find a way to do it, any suggestions?

```
    <Table // antd table 
        loading={Boolean(!data)} 
        rowKey={'id'} expandable={expandable}  
        pagination={{pageSize: 5}} 
        columns={columns} 
        dataSource={data}
    />

    render: (text, record) => ( // fragment from column object, which contain in column that'll be rendered
    <Space size="middle">
        <Dropdown overlay={() => DropMenu()}> //Where the dropdown compoennt is being called
            <a className="ant-dropdown-link" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
                Mais Opções <DownOutlined />
            </a>
        </Dropdown>
    </Space>

  const DropMenu = () => { //Dropdown Component

  return (
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Item>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="http://www.taobao.com/"> // Here I'll trigger the modal
          trigger modal
        </a>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually realized that antd has a Modal.confirm() which is a function that renders a confirmation modal with an ok and cancel button which you handle your own way.

```
<Menu.Item danger>
  <span onClick={() => confirm({id: record.id})}>Delete</span>
</Menu.Item>

function confirm({name, id}) {
   Modal.confirm({
      title: 'Confirm',
      icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
      content: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user??',
      okText: 'Confirmar',
      cancelText: 'Cancelar',
      onOk: (close) => { ...handling deletion }
   )}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
<Menu
    items={[
      {
        key: 1,
        label: <div onClick={() => edit()}>edit</div>,
      },
    ]}
/>
```